# Laravel: How to pass the value api data to view file

Tags: php, laravel

Using the **Laravel API**, which i try basic selecting data from database.

I have question regarding fetching the data from the API to a html page.

**My Controller:**

```
    class ContentController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function first_data() {
        $table_slider = DB::select('SELECT content_id,link,file,slider_sorting,content_pages FROM content_structure as cs LEFT JOIN (SELECT cid,file FROM content_upload_assets) cua ON cs.content_id = cua.cid WHERE content_pages = ? AND cs.status = ? ORDER BY content_id DESC ',[
            'Slider',
            'Active'
        ]);
        return View('fetch_first_data',['jsondata' => json_encode($table_slider)]);
    }


    public function fetch_first_data() {

        return View('fetch_first_data');

    }
}
```

View: fetch_first_data.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    {{$jsondata}}
</body>
</html>
```

In my web.php router:

```
Route::get('/fetch_first_data','ContentController@fetch_first_data');
```

In my api.php router:

```
Route::get('first_data','ContentController@first_data');
```

Question:

1. How to pass the value of /api/first_data to my view page.

Comment: why do you want to use VIEW? just make route for first_data method

Comment: what do you mean Gulshan

Answer (score 3):

```
public function first_data() {
    $table_slider = DB::select('SELECT content_id,link,file,slider_sorting,content_pages FROM content_structure as cs LEFT JOIN (SELECT cid,file FROM content_upload_assets) cua ON cs.content_id = cua.cid WHERE content_pages = ? AND cs.status = ? ORDER BY content_id DESC ',[
        'Slider',
        'Active'
    ]);
    return View('fetch_first_data',['jsondata' => json_encode($table_slider)]);
}
```

And in your blade file just print **{{$jsondata}}**.

Comment: in what blade file should i print the data?

Comment: fetch_first_data blade file

Comment: just add {{$jsondata}} in your fetch_first_data blade file in your views folder

Comment: Undefined variable: jsondata (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\LaravelAPI\resources\views\fetch_first_data.blade.php)

Comment: which verison of laravel you are using and can you please share what you have wrote in your blade file ?

Comment: @DevGe Can you also paste your route for `fetch_first_data`

Comment: Route::get('/fetch_first_data','ContentController@fetch_first_data');

Comment: @DevGe, please check if you are editing the same function, In the question you have mentioned the function name as `first_data`, but your route says `fetch_first_data`

Comment: @Saurabh the first_data route is in api.php then the fetch_first_data is in web.php

Comment: Thanks @GulshanPrajapati You're a savior. Worked great for my

Comment: @KapilVerma i already update my api result.. take alook the new update. there is no jsondata variable